# Parsing & Filtering JSON data from API into C# application

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

My goal is to retrieve JSON data from "The virus tracker" API and parse it into a label. This is for my IB personal project so I just started learning c#. Fount this old code and tried fixing it, it worked with basic GET API's but it doesn't work with the one I'm using. (English not my main language)

**POSTMAN RESPONSE**

```
{
   "results": [
      {
         "total_cases": 5954607,
         "total_recovered": 2622507,
         "total_unresolved": 2255875,
         "total_deaths": 363208,
         "total_new_cases_today": 53700,
         "total_new_deaths_today": 1659,
         "total_active_cases": 45257,
         "total_serious_cases": 2698001,
         "total_affected_countries": 213,
         "source": {
            "url": "https://thevirustracker.com/"
         }
      }
   ],
   "stat": "ok"
}
```

**C# CODE**

```
//Creating Client connection 
        RestClient restClient = new RestClient("https://thevirustracker.com/free-api?global=stats");


        //Creating request to get data from server
        RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("total_cases", Method.GET);


        // Executing request to server and checking server response to the it
        IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);


        // Extracting output data from received response
        string response = restResponse.Content;

        // Parsing JSON content into element-node JObject
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(restResponse.Content);

        //Extracting Node element using Getvalue method
        string cases = jObject.GetValue("total_cases").ToString();
        label1.Text = (cases);
```

**ERROR**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

My final goal with this code is that label1 says "5954607"

Remember that I'm really new to this so if you can explain the changes you made to the code ill really appreciate it.

Comment: It's helpful to know what error, if any, you're getting with the above code.  It's not enough to say, "It's not working".

Comment: You should look at what `jObject` is. Looking at the JSON, it's probably an object with two properties, `result` and `stat`, so `GetValue("total_cases")` is unlikely to return anything. You need to navigate into the `JArray` that is returned by `result`, get the first element, then get the value of the `total_cases` property.  Luckily, JSON.Net has [good documentation on querying JSON with LINQ](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using RestRequest correctly or initialized the RestClient wrongly.

If that url you used in the RestClient is the whole url then you don't need a "resource" in the RestRequest.

Due to that mistake you got an HTML response indicated by the error

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

The value of `restResponse.Content` probably starts with `<html` and that is not  valid JSON.

The Json payload is a bit more complex then you coded for. The results object holds an array with an object that has your stat property.

Putting these fixes together gives you this code.

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient("https://thevirustracker.com/free-api?global=stats");

//Creating request to get data from server
RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(null, DataFormat.Json);

// Executing request to server and checking server response to the it
IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);

// Extracting output data from received response
string response = restResponse.Content;

// Parsing JSON content into element-node JObject
var jObject = JObject.Parse(restResponse.Content);

//Extracting 
// the object has a results property 
// that is an array with one item (zero-based)
// on index 0 there is an object
// that has a property total_cases
string cases = (string) jObject["results"][0]["total_cases"];
label1.Text = (cases);
```

Comment: @zboy0 it is not a question if you can, you have to, according to the license: https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing

Comment: we need to use APA citing style, what do I put as your last name?

Comment: @zboy0 In all seriousness, [some authors only have one name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mononymous_person). When citing them, you should simply use the name you have (in this case, "rene"). [Here is a related question on Academia.SE about exactly this case with APA citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66033/how-to-cite-in-apa-format-for-an-author-who-uses-only-a-first-name).